# A question about splitting fields.

Tags: field-theory

Let $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ be two splitting fields of polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb{F[x]}$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

My textbook has a long proof for proving that $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are isomorphic.

But isn't this obvious? Aren't $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ equal, as both of them are the smallest field extensions of field $\mathbb{F}$ such that all the roots of $p(x)$ are contained within them?

EDIT: Obviously $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ can be constructed differently. But when they're fully constructed, they have to be the very same field! Hence, even if we considered different basis sets for them, $[E_{1}:F]=[E_{2}:F]$.

Comment: ...and your text book is...? I mean, it'd be interesting to know what *exactly* is the definition of "splitting field of polynomial" there.

Comment: For *the smallest field extension of $F$ such that all the roots...* to make sense, you need some field extension that contains all the roots to begin with. If you consider the question inside, e.g. a **fixed** algebraically closed field containing $F$, it would be simple. In general you have to **construct** the extension from scratch, and there is no reason to think that two different methods of construction would lead to the same result.

Comment: Herstein. It says _"a finite extension $E$ of $F$ is said to be a splitting field over $F$ for $f(x)$ if over $E[x]$, and not over any proper subfield, $f(x)$ can be factored as a product of linear factors"_

Comment: IOW, a student's imagination is easily lead astray here by being exposed only to extensions, where we can assume that everything takes place inside the field of complex numbers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- from what I understand, there can only be one smallest field containing all the elements of $\mathbb{F}$, and then some extra elements, i.e. the roots of $p(x)$ not contained within $F$. Let these roots be ${a,b,c\dots n}$. So aren't $E_{1}=E_{2}=F[a,b,c\dots n]$?

Comment: Of course this is contingent upon the fact that there is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}$ satisfied by $a$, an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F[a]}$ satisfied by $b$, and so on

Comment: In order to compare $E_1$ and $E_2$ for **equality** (as opposed to isomorphism), they would both need to be subsets of the same universe $\Omega$. Without such an universe you cannot compare them.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to shed some light to this by proffering several splitting fields of the polynomial $x^2+1$ over the rationals.

1. One splitting field is the field $\mathbb{Q}[i]$, i.e. the usual subfield of complex numbers.
2. Another splitting field is the quotient field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ of the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients by the maximal ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+1$.
3. Let us consider the skewfield of Hamiltonian quaternions
   $$
   \mathbb{H}=\{a+bi+cj+dj\mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\},
   $$
   where the usual relations are satisfied: $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$. Let us pick any triple $(b,c,d)$ of real numbers such that $b^2+c^2+d^2=1$. Then the quaternion
   $$
   u=bi+cj+dk
   $$
   satisfies the equation $u^2=-1$. It is easy to see that the subset
   $$
   \mathbb{Q}[u]=\{a+fu\in\mathbb{H}\mid a,f\in\mathbb{Q}\}
   $$
   is then a splitting field of $x^2+1$ over the rationals.
4. The set of matrices of the form
   $$
   \left(\begin{array}{rr}a&b\\-b&a\end{array}\right),
   $$
   with $a,b$ arbitrary rational numbers is yet another splitting field of $x^2+1$.

No two of these splitting fields are *equal* in an obvious sense. They are all isomorphic to each other, though.

---

Another example. You often think of the splitting field of $x^2-2$ over the rationals as $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$ - a subset of the real numbers. So then $\sqrt2$ may be a certain equivalence class of Cauch sequences. Why is that particular equivalence class of Cauchy sequence equal to the coset of $x$ in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$?

IOW. This questions is philosophical in the sense that we really are talking about the identity of the roots. Not just up to isomorphism!

Comment: Shouldn't the splitting firld in (1.) be $\mathbb{Q[i,-i]}$?

Comment: Well, yeah, but when you adjoin $i$, you get $-i$ free of charge.